# Connection to protected access accdb file throws "Wrong Password"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

I am trying to connect to an encrypted access 2013 accdb file which is using legacy encryption through an adodb vba procedure within an excel file.

The Procedure fails at cn.open, I am using office 64 bits, error message: "It is not a valid Password".
The particularity of this problem is, the password is correct, I can connect to the Access DB through Microsoft query just fine, and I can connect with another access DB with the code below. But when I try to use it on Excel, this error jumps in, take note, I have enabled the same references on both access and excel 
 vba editor.

My question is, how can I extract data from this password protected access file through excel, each and every method I try fail after I have typed the password.

VBA Procedure

```
Sub LDBViewer2010()
'Reference Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects for this code to work

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Const conDatabase As String = "E:\1.accdb"

    ' Open connection to Access backend
   cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & conDatabase & ";Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password='asd123';"

    ' Open recordset
   Set Rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, , "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")

    'Output the field list
   Debug.Print Rs.Fields(0).Name, "|", Rs.Fields(1).Name, "|", Rs.Fields(2).Name, "|", Rs.Fields(3).Name

    'Loop through users recordset of users in database.
   While Not Rs.EOF
        Debug.Print Trim(Rs.Fields(0)), "|", Trim(Rs.Fields(1)), "|", Trim(Rs.Fields(2)), "|", Trim(Rs.Fields(3))
        Rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    ' Close
   If Rs.State <> adStateClosed Then Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I greatly appreciate your time and help.

-Edit 1-

Using debug.print CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString in Access:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=E:1.accdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="";Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System.mdw;Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access\Access Connectivity Engine;Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=True;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False
```

Comment: At [connectionstrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) it says "**Note!** Reports say that a database encrypted using Access 2010 - 2013 default encryption scheme does not work with this connection string. In Access; try options and choose 2007 encryption method instead. That should make it work. We do not know of any other solution. ".

Comment: Do you have to use VBA for this? Can you not use Excel's built-in functionality to get data from an access database?

Comment: Hi Andy G, Thank you for the help, I am using the legacy encryption, not the new 2010 - 2013 scheme. This option is changed in File->Options->Client Configuration-> Ciphering method-> Use Hereditary ciphering.

Comment: You can likely work around this problem by automating Access, e.g. open up a new Access.Application object, open the database in there, and then using `app.CurrentProject.Connection` to get a valid ADODB connection.

Comment: @Zac I tried to use Excel built-in wizard to extract data from an access file. I works perfectly if the access file is not password protected, but if it is, it just loops endlessly at password prompt, whether I put a correct or incorrect password the prompt reappears with no error or message.

Comment: Can you use `Debug.Print CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString` from that Access file btw? Then we can see how Access connects to the database.

Comment: I don't work with access database (much). I have used that functionality with a non encrypted access databases but not with encrypted databases. This is interesting.. I'll keep an eye on this post

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth, Edited with the ConnectionString output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it creating a new access file and doing some further testing. Below is what I found out.

Although I created my database with hereditary encryption, the password always failed whichever the method. I tried Decrypting and Re-encrypting with same password and now excel connects just fine.

Take note that only excel had trouble connecting, I could connect from another access DB without a hitch.

Thank you for your ideas & contributions, they helped me get the right answer.