# In Access ACCDB file, when you use "Use legacy encryption", what is the encryption algorithm and how secure is it?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm in excel/vba, I need to open a password encrypted accdb database file.

According to

[connectionstrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) this feature is broken and always fails with a "Not a valid password" error

I have tried saving the same database as an mdb 2000, mdb 2003 and an accdb file each with an added password, they all open except accdb

I would like to know, when using accdb, if you enable legacy encrytion, do you get the cardboard-level protection of previous access version or something in-between ?

thanks !

More links

[Someone else with my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653890/connection-to-protected-access-accdb-file-throws-wrong-password)

[The solution so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045868/connecting-to-an-encrypted-access-database-after-changing-the-encryption-method)

[A method to change the encryption default with the office customization tool, I can't as I have no admin privileges](https://superuser.com/questions/669394/changing-encryption-settings-for-microsoft-office-2010-2013)

[Another method to change the encryption type in access 2007, using a 3rd party tool](https://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Changing-the-encryption-type-in-Access-2007)

Comment: Actually, the last link in your question answers the basic portion of your question rather thoroughly, IMHO.

Comment: I don't believe so, it says that the default encryption provider for post-2007 Access is RC4. That is the default, but it does not say what encryption is used when "legacy encryption" is select

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be possibly interested in 3rd party solutions, NetLib Encryptionizer provides seamless TDE to Access databases.  (Disclaimer: I am from [NetLib Security](https://netlibsecurity.com)).